# Ordering objects with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I honestly can't work out how to describe this succinctly so I can search for it.

I have two distinct objects, call them red and blue balls, and I have N of each in a bag, so the total balls in the bag is 2*N. I am drawing all 2*N balls out of the bag randomly and placing then in a line by the order that they are drawn.

I want to count the number of possible orders, considering that order is important between red and blue, but irrelevant for balls of the same colour.

I'm not sure if I've described this correctly, so here are the first 3 cases:
(I'm using 1 and 0 for clarity)

N=1,
10
01
No. ways=2

N=2,
1100
1010
1001
0110
0101
0011
No. ways=6

N=3,
111000
110100
110010
110001
101100
101010
101001
100110
100101
100011
011100
011010
011001
010110
010101
010011
001110
001101
001011
000111
No. ways=20 (I think)

I feel like this is obvious, but I just can't get it! Please put me out of my misery!

Comment: Search on google "variations with repetition" or "multisubsets".

Comment: $\binom{2N}N=\frac{(2N)!}{N!N!}$

Comment: Thanks! It was actually as simple as I suspected!
Would you be able to give a combinatorial explanation as to why this is the same as choosing n objects from 2n?

Comment: @Phill because is the same as permutations of 2N objects divided by undistinguishable permutations of each group of repeated elements. Forget the horrible definition of "choosing k objects on n", it is infinitely easier to think all problem of combinations just as permutations and derivations of permutations.